# In Redmine, how do I disable a built-in field?

Tags: field, redmine

The field I want to disable is the *Target Version* field, because some projects are not software projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you cannot hide the default fields in versions before 2.1.0: http://www.redmine.org/issues/1091